# gunicorn - unknown log output to console

Tags: python, flask, logging, gunicorn

I'm running my webservice with gunicorn and flask. I set the log output to log file, but found an unknown log record printed in console:
`[2021-04-19 14:26:42 +0800] [1717]: [INFO] POST http://127.0.0.1:9200/papers/_search [status:200 request:1.347s]`
I used elasticsearch in my service and this is the request sent to es server. I wanted this informatin to be printed in a file and have tried some methods, but none of thme worked. This is my gunicorn settings:

```
bind = "0.0.0.0:5001"
workers = 4
threads = 4
proc_name = "app"
logconfig_dict = {
    'version':1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    "root": {
          "level": "INFO",
          "propagate": True,
          "handlers": ["console"]
    },
    'loggers':{
        "gunicorn.error": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "handlers": ["error_file"], 
            "propagate": False, 
            "qualname": "gunicorn_error"
        },
        "gunicorn.access": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "handlers": ["access_file"],
            "propagate": False,
            "qualname": "access"
        }
    },
    'handlers':{
        "error_file": {
            "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
            "maxBytes": 1024*1024*100,
            "backupCount": 1,
            "formatter": "generic",
            "filename": "/home/wh/SearchEngine-test/log_file/gunicorn_error.log"
        },
        "access_file": {
            "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
            "maxBytes": 1024*1024*100,
            "backupCount": 1,
            "formatter": "generic",
            "filename": "/home/wh/SearchEngine-test/log_file/gunicorn_access.log",
        },
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            #"maxBytes": 1024*1024*100,
            #"backupCount": 1,
            'level': 'INFO',
            'formatter': 'generic',
            #"filename": "/home/wh/SearchEngine-test/log_file/gunicorn_console.log"
        },
    },
    'formatters':{
        "generic": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s [%(process)d]: [%(levelname)s] %(message)s",
            "datefmt": "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z]",
            "class": "logging.Formatter"
        }
    }
}
```

What's more, when i run gunicorn with command:
`gunicorn -w 4 --threads 4 -b 0.0.0.0:5001 main:app`
i didn't get this record anymore.
Could anyone help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write your errors to a log file:

```
--error-logfile yourfilename or --log-file yourfilename
```

For your access logs:

```
--access-logfile yourfilename
```

For more check [this](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html) documentation.

Comment: I have set these two loggers in my config file and they work well, but there is  still an unexpected log record printed in console.